# Xcode - Change button background colour on Button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this might have been asked before but, I've been trying to find an answer to this for ages. I am new to Xcode and would like to know, how do you change a buttons background colour when it is tapped?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code will change your button's background color to a blackColor.. You can change to whatever color you desire

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call setBackgroundColor: in method which fired when button pressed:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```